# Netbios network naming conflict

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2, netbios

Currently we have a server that's complaining about Netbios naming clashes with another machine on the network, after further checking into the problem we've found out that the server's vendor have set up the machine as the following

Server 1:
NetBios Name: Serv1
NIC 1: 192.168.1.1
NIC 2: 192.168.1.2

Our requirements for our vendor to have dual NIC for network teaming failover on the single network. But we've found out that they didn't do it so and configured the machine as the above. Both NICs are placed within the same network.

All if our applications (ie file sharing etc) queries Server 1 via it's NetBios name of Serv1. Will this cause any problems if we leave the problem as is since it's only the server complaining and not the clients? Or should we get the vendor to reconfigure the server?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this configuration will continue to cause problems. Disable one of the NICs immediately, then get the vendor to reconfigure the server with the two NICs teamed together and a single IP address.

See http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/32920-a-duplicate-name-has-been-detected-on-the-tcp-network